# Camera just a portion of a SurfaceView

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

Is it possible to draw the camera in just a portion of the SurfaceView?
or draw different things on the same SurfaceView?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve by that? You cannot send the camera preview to a portion of a SurfaceView, but you can adjust the size of this View, and put other views around it or even on top of it. The latter is an alternative to *drawing different things on the same SurfaceView*.

Comment: i have a server on the app, that is streaming the surfaceview (camera), i would like to stream other things.

Comment: You are using the SurfaceView as source of the image stream for your server, or as the target for your server?

Comment: the source is the camara, i'm watching the stream via VLC on the pc.

Comment: I believe that VLC will correctly display overlays over the SurfaceView.